# c# XlmWriter auto indenting string in written text

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I need to write an xml in C# and I want to make the text formatted.
These are my settings:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = ("\t"),
    NewLineChars = "\r\n",
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
};

XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(path + "//" + nome, settings);
```

After the header and the first nodes I should insert this string:

```
string st = "\r\nLINE 1\r\nLINE 2\r\nLINE 3\r\n";
```

And I would like to this to be formatted as follows:

```
    <Text>
          LINE 1
          LINE 2
          LINE 3
    </Text>
```

I wrote this code:

```
xmlWriter.WriteString(st);
```

Comment: Use `XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Text", st);` [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aex0e7zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or depending on complexity use a `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve such a result you should implement a custom `XmlWriter`:

```
public class IndentTextXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    private int indentLevel;
    private bool isInsideAttribute;

    public IndentTextXmlWriter(TextWriter textWriter): base(textWriter)
    {
    }

    public bool IndentText { get; set; }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        isInsideAttribute = true;
        base.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        isInsideAttribute = false;
        base.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        indentLevel++;
        base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        indentLevel--;
        base.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || isInsideAttribute || Formatting != Formatting.Indented || !IndentText || XmlSpace == XmlSpace.Preserve)
        {
            base.WriteString(text);
            return;
        }

        string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string indent = new string(IndentChar, indentLevel * Indentation);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine);
            WriteRaw(indent);
            WriteRaw(line.Trim());
        }

        WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine);
        WriteRaw(new string(IndentChar, (indentLevel - 1) * Indentation));
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WriteIndentedText()
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new IndentTextXmlWriter(new StringWriter(result)){Formatting = Formatting.Indented, IndentText = true})
    {
        string text = @" Line 1
Line 2
    Line 3  ";
        // some root
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("root");
        writer.WriteStartElement("child");

        // test auto-indenting
        writer.WriteStartElement("elementIndented");
        writer.WriteString(text);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        // test space preserving
        writer.WriteStartElement("elementPreserved");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xml", "space", null, "preserve");
        writer.WriteString(text);

        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

And the output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <child>
    <elementIndented>
      Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
    </elementIndented>
    <elementPreserved xml:space="preserve"> Line 1
Line 2
    Line 3  </elementPreserved>
  </child>
</root>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your comprehensive answer , one thing , you can tell me how to pass the folder in which to save the xml ( the string path)

Comment: Add another constructor: `public IndentTextXmlWriter(string filename, Encoding encoding): base(filename, encoding) {}`

Comment: this class properly indenting the virtual variable but writes erroneously files, why?
using (var = new xmlWriter IndentTextXmlWriter (path + "//" + name, Encoding.UTF8) = {Formatting Formatting.Indented, IndentText = true})

Comment: What is the problem with the files?

Comment: into the stingbuilder your class indentation are perfect, when i open the xml file is not indented

Comment: What do you mean you open it? If it is opened in Internet Explorer, for example, then it replaces the new lines to simple spaces. But if I open the result in Notepad, I see exactly the same as in the output above.

Comment: ok, open the file via explorer, opening it with sublime text is perfect, thanks again